# Keeping track of chess pieces

Tags: java, swing

I'm building a chess gui; I have a grid of buttons which make the chess board and I set the images of each chess piece as the button icon. The way this works is that each chess piece has its own class which extends the Piece super class. Each of those classes has a getImage() method which returns the corresponding image. I then set that image as the button icon.

Now that I am in the midst of implementing the rules of chess, I realized that I need to know the location of each chess piece. I have come up with two solutions to this problem

1. Keep track of the coordinates in instance variables. Put the entire object on the button so that it can easily be retrieved.
2. Get the coordinate every time a button is clicked. Basically, a button on the board is clicked, I get the coordinates of that button, and I get the piece that is on that button by passing the icon of that button through some identifier method that I'll have to write. I can then use this information to then use my logic methods such as getLegalMoves() etc.

I started writing the code with option 2 in mind but it got overly complicated really fast. I think it is possible to write a lot cleaner code if I go with option 1.

My problem is that I don't know how to put a complete object on top of a button so that not only will the object's image be displayed on the button, but also the object itself can easily be accessed. This way I can simply pass the object into my logic methods.

Is such a solution possible? I am using gridlayout with JButtons on a JPanel for my chess board. I don't what else you might need so just ask for any further details.

Comment: You should have started with the model.  The model determines the rules under which it can changed and maintains the state of all the pieces.  The UI then updates it's state based on the state of the model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this situation it is an absolute **must** that you separate out the GUI, the *View*, from the program logic, or *Model*. The locations of the pieces is part of the model and so should not be tracked by the GUI. The only job for the GUI is to display the state of the model and to report to the model, via the Control, when the user tries to change its state. So I suggest that you create your Model, which will likely be a complex beast composed of several classes or more. It will have logical class that represents the Board, a ChessSquare, the ChessPieces, the Moves, the legal moves for a piece, the Users, and any AI engine as well.

A good rule of thumb is to write the model so that it is GUI library agnostic, meaning that it should work well with a Swing GUI, a console program, an online program or maybe even an Android program.

Comment: That last sentence is what I think I was lacking in my understanding of MVC. Keeping that in mind I was able to separate out the pieces from the gui and this will allow me to make my program a lot simpler. Thank you for the help